# Does the logarithm function grow slower than any arbitrarily slow polynomial in the limit?

Tags: limits, polynomials, logarithms

We know a logarithm is slower than any polynomial of fixed degree. My question is on their relationship when the power is arbitrarily small, then what is the relationship with a logarithm in the limit? Specifically, for any given x> 1, and any fixed c\ge 1, can we always find a small enough t>0, so that x^t\le c*(log x)?

Comment: You can call $\,x^t\,$ a power, but it's not a polynomial when $\,t \not \in \mathbb N\,$.

Comment: If $x>1$, this is trivial. And if $x\le 1$, it's false.

Comment: not sure of how it is trivial when x>1. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's only true if $c\log x>1$. (But it's still trivial.)

Comment: @xxinverse.xy Are you sure your updated question is indeed your question? Think about what happens to $c\log x $ and  $x^t$ as $x\to 1^+$.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the limit in question is not well defined since

$$\lim_{x\to \infty }\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\log x}{x^t}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\log x=+\infty,\\
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{\log x}{x^t}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}0=0.\\$$

Comment: The question is well-posed. Specifically, the last sentence poses an explicit question, that doesn't involve limits at all.

Comment: @TonyK The question has been changed..

Comment: Yes, you are right. I removed my downvote.